# =IF(AND keeps ignoring the checks for some records

Tags: excel

```
=IF(AND([@[Discount (Y/N)]]="Y",[@count]=2),"10%",IF([@count]>2,"15%","0"))
```

Can someone tell me why my formula above does not work? It keeps bypassing the check for "Y" for some records. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is a part of the table with results of the formula in the final column. As you see record four should not be discounted as it does not meet both criteria for the check. Check it several times but I can seem to find the error.

```
+---+-----------+---+-----+
| N |  £160.00  | 2 | 0   |
| Y |  £160.00  | 2 | 10% |
| N |  £200.00  | 4 | 15% |
| Y |  £200.00  | 4 | 15% |
| Y |  £200.00  | 4 | 15% |
| Y |  £200.00  | 4 | 15% |
+---+-----------+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the check for Y into the second condition.

```
=IF(AND([@[Discount (Y/N)]]="Y", [@count]=2), 0.1, IF(AND([@[Discount (Y/N)]]="Y", [@count]>2), 0.15, 0))
```

Format the cell(s) as percentage.

[image]

Comment: Oh dear, tried this and it all change to 0 in the output column

Comment: All zeros appeared in the output coloumn

Comment: I've added a screenshot for comparison.

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I need. Thanks so much Jeeped :-)